# Книга рекордов Гиннесса

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать название этой книги? В кавычках или нет? И правильно ли написано "книга" и "Гиннесса" с прописной, а "рекордов" — со строчной?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насчет прописных и строчных. Слово **Книга** пишется с прописной, потому что это первое слово названия. Слово **Гиннесс** (Guinness) является именем собственным (название пивоваренной компании, по заказу которой этот сборник был впервые опубликован). Слово **рекорд** - нарицательное существительное, пишется со строчной. В "Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации" под ред. Лопатина это название дается без кавычек: **Книга рекордов Гиннесса.** (Обращаю внимание на написание слова *Гиннесса*: удвоенное НН и удвоенное СС).